# How do I apply bootstrap in asp dropdownlist getting data from an objectdatasource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

How do I apply bootstrap in asp dropdownlist getting data from an objectdatasource?

The old code is running perfectly.
Here's the old code

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="uxLocations" runat="server" 
                  DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" 
                  Height="24px" Width="200px" AutoPostBack="True" 
                  onselectedindexchanged="uxLocations_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
                      SelectMethod="GetLocations" 
                      TypeName="Domain.LocationManager">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

I tried to apply bootstrap but the list is not showing properly, unlike when you hardcode the list using "ul and li" tags, just as shown in http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_dropdowns.asp

Here's what i did: [not good]

```
<div class="dropdown">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="menu1" 
 data-toggle="dropdown">Locations
<span class="caret"></span></button>

<asp:DropDownList ID="uxLocations" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 CssClass="dropdown-menu" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
 DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" Height="24px" Width="200px">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetLocations" 
    TypeName="Domain.LocationManager">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

</div>
```

Help.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap's button dropdowns don't work with select elements. You'll have to roll your own or use something like [bootstrap-select](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select).

Using bootstrap-select, you'd simply set the CssClass on the drop-down control to "selectpicker" like so:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="uxLocations" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
 CssClass="selectpicker" DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
 DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: Tnx, I checked on bootstrap-select, I think I'd be needing that next time, For now i just used CssClass="form-control". :) tnx

Answer (score 0):

I used the CssClass="form-control" instead of CssClass="dropdown-menu", I tried to use button dropdown style but I need to finish quickly. I think this suffice my needs for now. Also thanks for the bootstrap-select, I'd be exploring that later.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="box">

<asp:DropDownList ID="uxLocations" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" CssClass="form-control"
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="ID" 
    Height="35px" Width="200px">
</asp:DropDownList>

<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetLocations" 
    TypeName="CPRG255.InlandMarina.Domain.LocationManager">
</asp:ObjectDataSource>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```